# Batch renaming files on command line

Tags: bash

I'm looking to rename a series of files that has the following naming system:

```
5901_fig-1658008.20.peg.1782.faa
7274_fig-1658008.20.peg.2807.faa
8228_fig-1658008.20.peg.3705.faa
```

And change it to:

```
fig-1658008.20.peg.1782.faa
fig-1658008.20.peg.2807.faa
fig-1658008.20.peg.3705.faa
```

How would I do this on command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you just want to remove the sub strings before '_'

```
 for file in *.faa; do mv "$file" "${file#*_}"; done
```